# C# simultaneous execution of resources-monitoring logic and other tasks

Tags: c#

I am developing a program which will run on thin clients with minimum multitasking capabilities and other hardware resources.
I wish to have two methods running continuously but not hold the flow of the program. During my search I came across some posts that try to address similar concepts but they are quite old and either in a different programming language or do not solve my problem.

In my program I have a file system watcher, a resources monitor method, and some other methods.

Currently my program runs file system watcher and ResourcesMonitor() method in parallel but the program does not get past ResourcesMonitor() method so the ThirdMethod() and other following methods never execute.

How can I have my program run ResourcesMonitor() and also execute the remaining methods below this method?

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // call the FSW
        var task = MyFileSystemWatcher(path);

        // call another method that works same way as file system watcher
        ResourcesMonitor();  

        // call another method
        ThirdMethod();

        // more methods
    }

    private void ResourcesMonitor()
    {

        // on a thin client with limited hardware resources

        using (an API)
        {
            // monitors...
        // if number of processes is higher than recommended, close some uncessary background processes
        // in the cases of resources overflow, write to log


            // to have the this method run infinitely
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
        }
    }

    private static void ThirdMethod()
    {
        // does something
    }

    private static async Task MyFileSystemWatcher(string path)
    {
        // file system watcher
    }

}
```

Currently I have two such methods but may have more methods with a similar logic later that I will have to run in parrallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task` to accomplish this:

```
    // call another method that works same way as file system watcher
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => ResourcesMonitor());

    // call another method
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => ThirdMethod());


    Task.WaitAll(new { task1, task2 } );
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, I think I read somewhere that `Task.Run(() => Method())` may require higher processing resources from the processor, is that true?

Comment: FileWatcher uses delegates to effectively 'callback' your code when something happens, so this doesn't require a task.  Other than that, if your code 'blocks' waiting for something, then a `Task` will do the job.  As to if this is the 'best' approach, that depends on how experienced you are as a developer.  Threads are another option but require slightly more management.

Comment: It seems to be working, thank you Neil. Although I am not sure what `Task.WaitAll(new { task1, task2 } );` does as the program seems to be working without this line of code. Could you suggest if I need this?

Comment: WaitAll stops the program to wait until tasks are completed. If your tasks run indefinitely, you probably don't need this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Timofeus You will need SOMETHING to stop the program ending, otherwise it will just fall out of Main and the program will exit.  You could just as easily use `Console.ReadLine()`.  Personally, I prefer that programs exit 'cleanly', so all my tasks are capable of completing.

Comment: @Neil, yes, of course, my point was that if the task is not supposed to exit by itself, waiting it in main thread will simply hang the program.

Answer (score 0):

Create new Thread with the method you need, optionally make it background and assign priority level as you need (there are several).

Comment: Thanks Timofeus, but I am not very comfortable with usiing Threads. Also, a multi-threaded program may not run properly on a device with hardware limitations.

Comment: To think of it, do make it background, unless there are reasons not to.